# Semibold math symbols?

Tags: math-fonts

Is there a way to make semibold math symbols?
I am using \mathbf for vector symbols, but I feel they look too heavy.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % useful to type directly accentuated characters
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{sansmath} \sansmath
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\[
\vc f_s^{ij} = k_s \vc r_{ij} \frac{\| \vc x_j - \vc x_i \| - \mathnormal{l}_0}{\mathnormal{l}_0}
\]
\end{document}
```

I tried the package bm, but it did not change the fonts, as far as I can see.

Is there a way to make semibold vector symbols?
I have already googled (and found a few hits here on SE), but none of the suggestions worked for me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards, Gabriel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a semibold condensed in the cmss family.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no needed anymore in a current latex, it is the default 
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathsb}{OT1}{cmss}{sbc}{n}
\newcommand{\vcsb}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsb{#1}}} %semibold
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{sansmath} \sansmath
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\[
\vc f_s^{ij} = k_s \vc r_{ij} \frac{\| \vc x_j - \vc x_i \| - \mathnormal{l}_0}{\mathnormal{l}_0}
\]

\[
\vcsb f_s^{ij} = k_s \vcsb r_{ij} \frac{\| \vcsb x_j - \vcsb x_i \| - \mathnormal{l}_0}{\mathnormal{l}_0}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That does exactly what I wanted ...